# A producer consumer queue with an additional thread for a periodic backup of data

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading

I'm trying to implement a concurrent producer/consumer queue with multiple producers and one consumer: the producers add some data to the `Queue`, and the consumer dequeues these data from the queue in order to update a collection. This collection must be periodically backed up to a new file. For this purpose I created a custom serializable collection: serialization could be performed by using the `DataContractSerializer`.

- The queue is only shared between the consumer and the producers, so access to this queue must be managed to avoid race conditions.
- The custom collection is shared between the consumer and a backup thread.
- The backup thread could be activated periodically using a [`System.Threading.Timer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/system.threading.timer%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) object: it may initially be scheduled by the consumer, and then it would be scheduled at the end of every backup procedure.
- Finally, a shutdown method should stop the queuing by producers, then stop the consumer, perform the last backup and dispose the timer.

The dequeuing of an item at a time may not be efficient, so I thought of using two queues: when the first queue becomes full, the producers notify the consumer by invoking `Monitor.Pulse`. As soon as the consumer receives the notification, the queues are swapped, so while producers enqueue new items, the consumer can process the previous ones.

The sample that I wrote seems to work properly. I think it is also thread-safe, but I'm not sure about that. The following code, for simplicity I used a `Queue<int>`. I also used (again for simplicity) an `ArrayList` instead of collection serializable.

```
public class QueueManager
{
    private readonly int m_QueueMaxSize;
    private readonly TimeSpan m_BackupPeriod;

    private readonly object m_SyncRoot_1 = new object();
    private Queue<int> m_InputQueue = new Queue<int>();
    private bool m_Shutdown;
    private bool m_Pulsed;

    private readonly object m_SyncRoot_2 = new object();
    private ArrayList m_CustomCollection = new ArrayList();

    private Thread m_ConsumerThread;
    private Timer m_BackupThread;
    private WaitHandle m_Disposed;

    public QueueManager()
    {
        m_ConsumerThread = new Thread(Work) { IsBackground = true };

        m_QueueMaxSize = 7;
        m_BackupPeriod = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30);
    }

    public void Run()
    {
        m_Shutdown = m_Pulsed = false;

        m_BackupThread = new Timer(DoBackup);
        m_Disposed = new AutoResetEvent(false);

        m_ConsumerThread.Start();
    }

    public void Shutdown()
    {
        lock (m_SyncRoot_1)
        {
            m_Shutdown = true;
            Console.WriteLine("Worker shutdown...");

            Monitor.Pulse(m_SyncRoot_1);
        }

        m_ConsumerThread.Join();
        WaitHandle.WaitAll(new WaitHandle[] { m_Disposed });

        if (m_InputQueue != null) { m_InputQueue.Clear(); }
        if (m_CustomCollection != null) { m_CustomCollection.Clear(); }

        Console.WriteLine("Worker stopped!");
    }

    public void Enqueue(int item)
    {
        lock (m_SyncRoot_1)
        {
            if (m_InputQueue.Count == m_QueueMaxSize)
            {
                if (!m_Pulsed)
                {
                    Monitor.Pulse(m_SyncRoot_1); // it notifies the consumer...
                    m_Pulsed = true;
                }
                Monitor.Wait(m_SyncRoot_1);  // ... and waits for Pulse
            }

            m_InputQueue.Enqueue(item);
            Console.WriteLine("{0}    \t {1} >", Thread.CurrentThread.Name, item.ToString("+000;-000;"));
        }
    }

    private void Work()
    {
        m_BackupThread.Change(m_BackupPeriod, TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(-1));

        Queue<int> m_SwapQueueRef, m_WorkerQueue = new Queue<int>();

        Console.WriteLine("Worker started!");
        while (true)
        {
            lock (m_SyncRoot_1)
            {
                if (m_InputQueue.Count < m_QueueMaxSize && !m_Shutdown) Monitor.Wait(m_SyncRoot_1);

                Console.WriteLine("\nswapping...");
                m_SwapQueueRef = m_InputQueue;
                m_InputQueue = m_WorkerQueue;
                m_WorkerQueue = m_SwapQueueRef;

                m_Pulsed = false;
                Monitor.PulseAll(m_SyncRoot_1); // all producers are notified
            }

            Console.WriteLine("Worker\t      < {0}", String.Join(",", m_WorkerQueue.ToArray()));

            lock (m_SyncRoot_2)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Updating custom dictionary...");
                foreach (int item in m_WorkerQueue)
                {
                    m_CustomCollection.Add(item);
                }
                Thread.Sleep(1000);
                Console.WriteLine("Custom dictionary updated successfully!");
            }

            if (m_Shutdown)
            {
                // schedule last backup
                m_BackupThread.Change(0, Timeout.Infinite);
                return;
            }
            m_WorkerQueue.Clear();
        }
    }

    private void DoBackup(object state)
    {
        try
        {
            lock (m_SyncRoot_2)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Backup...");
                Thread.Sleep(2000);
                Console.WriteLine("Backup completed at {0}", DateTime.Now);
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            if (m_Shutdown) { m_BackupThread.Dispose(m_Disposed); }
            else { m_BackupThread.Change(m_BackupPeriod, TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(-1)); }
        }
    }
}
```

Some objects are initialized in the `Run` method to allow you to restart this `QueueManager` after it is stopped, as shown in the code below.

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    QueueManager queue = new QueueManager();

    var t1 = new Thread(() =>
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++)
        {
            queue.Enqueue(i);
            Thread.Sleep(1500);
        }
    }) { Name = "t1" };

    var t2 = new Thread(() =>
    {
        for (int i = 0; i > -30; i--)
        {
            queue.Enqueue(i);
            Thread.Sleep(3000);
        }
    }) { Name = "t2" };

    t1.Start(); t2.Start(); queue.Run();
    t1.Join(); t2.Join(); queue.Shutdown();
    Console.ReadLine();

    var t3 = new Thread(() =>
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++)
        {
            queue.Enqueue(i);
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
        }
    }) { Name = "t3" };

    var t4 = new Thread(() =>
    {
        for (int i = 0; i > -30; i--)
        {
            queue.Enqueue(i);
            Thread.Sleep(2000);
        }
    }) { Name = "t4" };

    t3.Start(); t4.Start(); queue.Run();
    t3.Join(); t4.Join(); queue.Shutdown();
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest using the `BlockingCollection` for a producer/consumer queue.  It was designed specifically for that purpose.  The producers add items using `Add` and the consumers use `Take`.  If there are no items to take then it will block until one is added.  It is already designed to be used in a multithreaded environment, so if you're just using those methods there's no need to explicitly use any locks or other synchronization code.